# function triggers on click

Tags: javascript, html

How do I trigger this function:

```
<script>
        function change(x) {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");

         if (y == "imgA") {target.className = "cast1";}
    else if (y == "imgB") {target.className = "cast2";}
    else if (y == "imgC") {target.className = "cast3";}
    else if (y == "imgD") {target.className = "cast4";}
    else {target.className = "chart";}
}

function changeReset() {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    target.className = "chart";
}
</script>
```

To only happen when this button is pressed?

```
<div class='nfooter' style="position:float;"><a id="c_question" href="#"><img src="../name_footer/_name.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: You can use `document.getElementById("c_question")` and `addEventListener` or you can add to the `onclick` attribute to the `a` link. The former is the more preferred method.

Comment: What button? I see a div, an anchor, and an image.

Comment: Which of the two functions do you wish to attach? Also, what is the the argument to `change` supposed to be?

Comment: `'need2nobasis'.replace('is', 'ics');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `onclick="change()"` to the element.

Edit:

```
function change(x) {
    if(x=="something"){
        var target = document.getElementById("target");

        if (y == "imgA") {target.className = "cast1";}
        else if (y == "imgB") {target.className = "cast2";}
        else if (y == "imgC") {target.className = "cast3";}
        else if (y == "imgD") {target.className = "cast4";}
        else {target.className = "chart";}
   }
}
```

Alternately if you mean to only allow the function to execute when called by a particular element you can check the element. The `this` reference will refer to the element that owns the function.

```
function change(x) {
    if(this.id == "target")
        var target = document.getElementById("target");

        if (y == "imgA") {target.className = "cast1";}
        else if (y == "imgB") {target.className = "cast2";}
        else if (y == "imgC") {target.className = "cast3";}
        else if (y == "imgD") {target.className = "cast4";}
        else {target.className = "chart";}
   }
}
```

Edit2:

Normally you would bind using `element.onclick` however when using the inline declaration the `this` reference refers to the window.

Details here http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Without changing your code too much you can change your function slightly as suggested below.

```
function change(element,x) {
    if(element.id=="target"){
        var target = document.getElementById("target");

        if (y == "imgA") {target.className = "cast1";}
        else if (y == "imgB") {target.className = "cast2";}
        else if (y == "imgC") {target.className = "cast3";}
        else if (y == "imgD") {target.className = "cast4";}
        else {target.className = "chart";}
   }
}
```

Then change your inline onclick to pass a reference to the element. `onclick="change(this,'target')"`

Generally its considered bad practice to use inline onclick declarations. So consider doing your click binding in script.

Comment: can I onclick=change('target') so if there is another function anywhere in the code, it will not trigger without a specific reference by id target?

Comment: How do you mean? If you mean can you check for a specific target you can do that in your function. If you mean another change function with different parameters, that is something you can't do in javascript. It's called function overloading and isn't supported.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'check in your function'

Comment: oh yeah, I noticed that.  Thanks for everything. Very much appreciated.  I added return false as well

Comment: I am using the this reference, but I keep getting nothing returned with the following code.  <div class='nfooter' style="position:float; z-index:1200;"><a id="target" onclick="change('target');" href="#"><img src="../name_footer/_name.png" /></a></div>

Comment: I've updated the code again and including a helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

add another parameter object in function definition and in function call use 'this'
and check in function definition by id that object.id is that of u desire.hope u got the logic.